# Mapping Godaddy custom domain to Azure CDN endpoint

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, azure-storage, cdn

I have an Azure CDN Profile with origin host name `https://mysite.z8.web.core.windows.net` and endpoint hostname `https://mysite.azureedge.net`. I would like to be able to access my static site from `www.mysite.io` (using GoDaddy). I am struggling with adding this mapping from my domain to the CDN endpoint. I have read through a bunch of tutorials but am still stuck.

Have I modified/added my CNAME records correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same in my environment.

Go to your Domain Registrar --> Add a CNAME Record with Name as your subdomain and value as the azure CDN endpoint.

[image]

Open Azure Portal --> Go to your CDN Profile --> Click on the endpoint which was created for Storage Static Website --> Click on Add Custom Domain --> Enter the custom hostname as your subdomain --> Click on Add

[image]

Now you would be able to access your static website using your custom domain.